# Choosing between a struct to unpack, extern variable, or long argument list

Tags: c, struct, arguments, parameter-passing, extern

I was curious if there is a common convention regarding how to pass a lot of values to a function (both in general and when the function will be called several times with the same values).  For example, which of these might be preferable:

```
int function(int val1, int val2, int val3, int val4, int val5, int val6, int val7)
{
    return val1+val2+val3+val4+val5+val6+val7;
}
```

or

```
struct int_struct {
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int val3;
    int val4;
    int val5;
    int val6;
    int val7;
};

int function(struct int_struct * ints)
{
    int val1 = int_struct->val1;
    int val2 = int_struct->val2;
    int val3 = int_struct->val3;
    int val4 = int_struct->val4;
    int val5 = int_struct->val5;
    int val6 = int_struct->val6;
    int val7 = int_struct->val7;

    return val1+val2+val3+val4+val5+val6+val7;
}
```

or (mostly in the case that the function will be called several times with the same arguments)

```
extern int val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7;

int function(void)
{
    return val1+val2+val3+val4+val5+val6+val7;
}
```

> Does which one is preferable depend on whether code readability or performance are more important for the particular project?

Comment: How about an array? If the values have different types, then a struct.

Comment: The global variables suggestion should be shot, buried, forgotten — immediately.

Comment: Without seeing the call sites, it is hard to know what's going to be best.  You've omitted one option — passing a pointer to a structure instead of a copy of the structure.  (Your notation originally used `->` in place of `.` — maybe I edited the wrong way.  There are two ways to pass structures — by value and by pointer.)  If the structure could be useful in the main computation, it may make sense (especially the pass by pointer variant).  The unpacking into local variables before adding them up is not necessary; fortunately, the compiler probably won't do it and will optimize the code.

Comment: There's a bit of code smell to a function that requires a lot of separate parameters (where the definition of "a lot" is subject to debate).  Surely in such cases, if the function is sensible at all then there is some kind of relationship among the arguments; argument types probably should be chosen to encompass and express that relationship.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, it was supposed to be a pointer.  Hopefully it's alright now.  And it would perform more complex operations with the local variables, some of them being pointers that it would change the contents of.

Comment: @DeiDei Yeah, different types.